# ASP.NET C# Reportviewer height issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, height, reportviewer

I have searched and gone through many sites but not getting solution for problem.

I am having report viewer in my asp.net page. i want the  report viewer to be visible in full page.
i tried to specify height but it dosen't workout for me.

[image]

i want this control to be displayed in full page size. Show me some guide line to set Height of this control.

Here is my code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="SiteManager_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Visible="true" AsyncRendering="false"
        SizeToReportContent="true" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { $('#<%=ReportViewer1.ClientID%>_fixedTable').css('width', '100%'); });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I use with ReportViewer 2010 and jQuery (something like a hack, but it works ;-)

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer runat="server" ID="rv1" Visible="true" AsyncRendering="false" SizeToReportContent="true" />
```

then

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){$('#<%=rv1.ClientID%>_fixedTable').css('width','100%');});
</script>
```

Hope this will help ;-

Comment: Updated my question with my Code. please have a look and point me out what i need to do ... thanks.

Comment: hi this worked after some fixing..my report was expecting parameters and if i dont suppy it frm asp.net page it wont show me the report..i supplied parameters and now it works fine..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"

ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="100%" Hieght="100%" CssClass="fullheight">
```

Try this...

Comment: this gives full widht but it doesnt effect on height.. the issue remains same..:( any other way ??